# How to change Tor exit node when using multiple SocksPorts?

Tags: exit-relays, linux, socks, protocol, stream-isolation

I'm using Tor with multiple SocksPorts. Does anyone know how I can programmatically change the exit for each SocksPort separately? The code below changes the exit nodes for all the SocksPorts -- I want to be able to do it individually. Is there a way to assign a separate control port to each SocksPort or tell the control port to change the exit node for a specific SocksPort?

```
echo -e 'AUTHENTICATE "password"\r\nsignal NEWNYM\r\nQUIT' | nc 127.0.0.1 9051
```

I'm on Linux. Thanks.

Comment: Seeing as the lack of response, is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know how I can programmatically change the exit for each SockPort separately?

I didn't see this in control-spec. It's an interesting problem. If you have multiple `SocksPort`, and are using applications which are configured to use a *specific* `SocksPort`, there is a less-than-elegant solution. Specific to application traffic the Tor process maintains `StreamID` and `CircuitID`. You can use `GETINFO stream-status` to associate application `StreamID` with `CircuitID`. Applications can have multiple streams though so this could only help if application traffic can be identified using `Target`. Another possible way to identify an application stream is by using `SETEVENTS STREAM` then watch events having `StreamStatus=NEW*` from an application's `SOURCE_ADDR`. I suppose if the application only creates a single stream at a time it would also work.

You would also need to set the `SessionGroup=INT` isolation flag for each `SocksPort`. Give each `SocksPort` it's own INT group and *applications won't share circuits*. All the streams on a particular circuit will be associated with the applications using a `SocksPort`. It helps if only a single application uses each `SocksPort`. This makes the next part more useful (and practical).

Basically, `CLOSECIRCUIT` the `CircuitID` that an application (identified by a stream, circuit, target combination) is using. Now in the future that application will use a new general-purpose circuit (if `__LeaveStreamsUnattached` is default). The application needs to know it has to create a new connection. In other words, you're essentially interrupting any existing streams on the circuit, which is less elegant than issuing `SIGNAL NEWNYM`. In the latter case the existing streams aren't interrupted but rather new streams are attached to a new circuit. This might not be a big deal if you usually initiate a new connection from the application after `SIGNAL NEWNYM`.

It depends on the applications though. If the applications break in unpredicatable ways when existing connections are interrupted you should be prepared. You'll find the documentation for [SessionGroup in Tor's manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) and the rest in [control-spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt).

> Is there a way to assign a separate control port to each `SocksPort`

Nope.

> or tell the control port to change the exit node for a specific `SocksPort`

Nope.

I know it's not what you were hoping for but I hope that helps! You might also find [txtorcon](https://txtorcon.readthedocs.org/) useful for this task.

-- leeroy

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do that is to run multiple Tor clients. Each with their own SOCKS port and their own exit node.

Answer (score 1):

Tor doesn't require SOCKS5 login/password authentication but it creates different circuits for each unique login/password pair. So you can just use different random login/password to authenticate against SOCKS5 proxy to isolate you streams. 
You doesn't even need to use **SIGNAL NEWNYM**, just change login/password to some random value and you will got new circuits and exit nodes.
You doesn't even need to use **different socks ports**, just change login/password to some random value and you will got new circuits and exit nodes.